# Event doesn't emit with router-link

Tags: vue.js, events

I have a simple Vue app:

```js
const Home = { template: '<div>Home</div>' }
const Bar = {
  methods: {
    bar () {
        alert('bar')
        this.$emit('test')
    }
  },
  template: `
     <div>
        <button  @click="bar()">Bar</button><br/>
        <router-link @click.native="bar()" to="/">Home</router-link>
     </div>
  `
}

const Foo = {
  components: { Bar },
  methods: {
    foo () {
        alert('foo')
    }
  },
  template: '<Bar @test="foo()" />'
}

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: Home },
    { path: '/foo', component: Foo }
  ]
})

new Vue({ router, el: '#app' })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tqp5yc6z/5/

By clicking `Bar` button in `Bar` component there will be two alerts with `bar` and `foo` texts. That's the expected behaviour.

But by clicking `Home` link in `Bar` component there will be only one alert with `bar` text, `test` event wouldn't be emitted, though `bar` method would be executed. I wonder why is that happening?

Answer (score 0):

That's because `Foo` component was already destroyed before `test` event was emitted.
The best solution here is to replace `<router-link @click.native="bar()" to="/">Home</router-link>` with `<button @click="goHome()">Home</button>` where `goHome` is:

```js
{
  methods: {
    goHome() {
      alert('bar')
      this.$emit('test')
      this.$router.push('/');
    }
  }
}
```